# Get K2 extra fields data in external script

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

Im trying to load data from extra_fields field from k2_items table inside external php script (let's call it locations.php) which I would like to include somewhere else on the site.

Data in extra_field field is json encoded:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"somevalue"},{"id":"2","value":"somevalue"},{"id":"3","value":"somevalue"}.]
```

For example: I have items with ids 1,6,10,15,22,44 and 66.
I would like to have variables for each extra field and for each item so I can use them elsewhere.
If item with id 1 has 3 extra fields, I would like to have variables $item1ExtraField1, $item1ExtraField2 and $item1ExtraField3.

So first I initiated Joomla framework:

```
// Get Joomla Framework
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once (JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once (JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once (JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Then I tried DB query with 2 ids to see if I can get data:

```
// Load the data from the database.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
->select('extra_fields')
->from('#__k2_items')
->where('id = 15 or id= 289');
$db->setQuery($query);
$items = $db->loadObjectList();

// Check for a database error.
if ($db->getErrorNum())
{
    $this->_subject->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
    return false;
}
```

Then I get slowly lost.
I get no results if I try:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo json_decode($item);
}
```

and var_dump gives me

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1395 (1) { ["extra_fields"]=> string(1013) "[{"id":"3","value":"somevalue"},{"id":"4","value":"somevalue"}, etc ]
```

or using jdump extension:

```
[array] (unknown name) 
    [stdClass object] 0
    Properties
        [string] extra_fields = "[{"id":"3","value":"somevalue"},{"id":"4","value":"somevalue"}, etc ]"
[stdClass object] 1
    Properties
        [string] extra_fields = "[{"id":"3","value":"somevalue"},{"id":"4","value":"somevalue"}, etc ]"
```

So Joomla framework initialization seems ok, DB connection is there, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->id;<br/> echo $item->value;
}

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is with decoding json string. Try something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$fields =(array)json_decode($item['extra_fields']);
$field1 = $fields[0]->value;
$field2 = $fields[1]->value;
}
```